# Setting the color of a button Back.Image (png)

Tags: ios, genexus, genexus-sd

Developing with GeneXus: I am trying to use this image as a Background for a Button in the Application Bar (iOS):

[image]

However, when I execute the app it always shows like this (blue):

[image]

I already tried to set the button class back/fore color to "white". Did the same for the ApplicationBar class (Default Button Class). Still it's blue.

I played a little with the button properties and... when I set the "Priority" to "High" it finally becomes white (but in the top bar - I want the button in the bottom).

How can I make it white / png color?

Comment: We just checked and there is a bug in the GeneXus iOS' Flexible Client. It will be fixed in Evolution 3 Upgrade 3, but as a work arround, you could use a white image and set the property Rendering Mode = Original. Please, if that doesn't work, send an email to support.

Comment: Hi, how exactly do I change the "Rendering Mode"? Where do I find this property?

Comment: Found the property and it solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your image is being rendered as a *template* image, so its colors don't matter - only transparency matters - and it is tinted with the `tintColor`. To change the color, change the `tintColor` (of the button or of the surrounding bar). Alternatively, derive an image whose rendering mode is `.AlwaysOriginal`; now your colors *do* matter.